# Is there a way to input a text file from phone's sdcard?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, text-files

I'm making a Phonegap app that requires a text file input from the user. I've tried using `<input type="file">` but it only allows me to choose a file from the gallery or a music file.

Is there any way for the user to browse the phone's sdcard using the native file browsers for a text file on both iOS and Android? Or is making my own file browser the only option available? Is there no simple way to let the user plug in a file to the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply: No

iOS don't have an accessible file system not even for developers. Also none of the iOS devices support SD cards.

Comment: Really? So there's absolutely no way to let the user input a file to the app? Are there any alternatives? I thought this would be a common use case :(

Comment: There is, but only to the app's sandbox. This means no other apps can reach into it.

Answer (score 0):

In android you can more do it.

To make your app compatible with standard text files by registering it into it's manifest file. Take a look at [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#npex) from google.

To access the files in the SD card, if for instance you want to scan for a certain file type, take a look at [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Answer (score 0):

//Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
//*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

//Get the text file

```
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");
```

//Read text from file

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
```

//Find the view by its id

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

//Set the text

```
tv.setText(text);
```